# How to Install RVM via Vagrant and Puppet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, puppet

I'm provisioning a new Vagrant box for Ruby on Rails development (using VirtualBox) and would like to add RVM + ruby 2.3.0 as part of the Vagrant provisioning process.

My Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.module_path    = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "development.pp"
  end

end
```

And puppet/manifests/development.pp:

```
class requirements {
  group { "puppet": ensure => "present", }
  exec { "apt-update":
    command => "/usr/bin/apt-get -y update"
  }

  package {
    ["mysql-client", "mysql-server", "libmysqlclient-dev"]: 
      ensure => installed, require => Exec['apt-update']
  }
}

include requirements
```

This just installs mysql at the moment. I'd like to add RVM + install a default ruby (2.3.0 for example).

There is this guide:
http://blog.csanchez.org/2014/01/14/installing-rvm-and-multiple-ruby-versions-with-puppet/

Which uses this puppet module:
https://forge.puppetlabs.com/maestrodev/rvm

I don't have puppet installed, because when I try to run:

```
puppet module install maestrodev-rvm
```

I get "-bash: puppet: command not found".

Looking through the Puppet docs, it appears rather complicated to install/setup a Puppet client/server. This seems like overkill just to use the RVM puppet module. Also, designers on the team will be using this process so it needs to be as simple as possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't have puppet installed

Yes, you do - puppet is installed on your VM, otherwise you would not be able to provision mysql and other.

You probably run the command `puppet module install maestrodev-rvm` from your host, while this needs to be run on the VM.

There are different ways how people have the modules setup on the VM (librarian, some downloads all in module/ folder...) what I do is to create a shell provisioning which will install all the necessary modules.
In your vagrantfile add

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "puppet/script/install-puppet-modules.sh"
```

make sure this line is before your puppet provision - the install-puppet-modules.sh will be something like

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules;

if [ ! -d /etc/puppet/modules/maestrodev/rvm ]; then
  puppet module install maestrodev-rvm --version xxx
fi
```

I like to make a point to the version so if there's a new version of the module in the forge it might break, at least I know that version xxx has been tested.

So now you're able to add `class { 'rvm': }` and so on to install rvm and ruby in your `puppet/manifests/development.pp` file